# QML ListView::contentWidth is wider than actual content

Tags: qt, qml

Trying to implement ListView's content scroll by clicking on a button. When scrolling towards the end of the view ListView's content does not stop at the end of the last picture it overscrolls. Below I provided the minimum working example as well as the preview what goes wrong. Just change the `.img` path to make it work on your PC. I was looking for some help in sources of ListView and its inherited parent Flickable but nothing that could help to resolve the problem. How to make it stop at the end of the last picture?

[image]

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 300

    Item {
        id: root

        anchors.fill:  parent

        property var imagesUrlModel: ["file:///C:/Users/mikha/OneDrive/Изображения/toyota.jpg",
            "file:///C:/Users/mikha/OneDrive/Изображения/toyota.jpg"
        ]

        property int _width: 0

        Component {
            id: imageDelegate

            Image {
                id: image

                sourceSize.height: 300

                source: modelData
                fillMode: Image.Stretch
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: leftButton
            anchors.top: root.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 15
            anchors.leftMargin: 10
            anchors.left: parent.left

            color: "green"

            width: 25

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    listView.contentX = listView.contentX > 0
                            ? listView.contentX - 50 > 0 ? listView.contentX - 50 : 0
                            : 0
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rightButton

            anchors.top: root.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.topMargin: 15
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.right: parent.right

            color: "green"

            width: 25

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    listView.contentX = listView.contentX < listView.contentWidth
                            ? listView.contentX + 50
                            : listView.contentWidth
                     //wrong content width
                }
            }
        }

        ListView{
            id: listView

            clip: true
            boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

            anchors.topMargin: 15
            anchors.left: leftButton.right
            anchors.right: rightButton.left
            anchors.top: root.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            spacing: 5
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal

            model: root.imagesUrlModel
            delegate: imageDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another approach with `repeater` and `scrollview` and it has worked!

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height: 300

    Item {
        id: contentItem
        anchors.fill: parent


        Rectangle {
            id: rightButton

            anchors.top: contentItem.top
            anchors.bottom: contentItem.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.right: contentItem.right

            color: "green"

            width: 25

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    var allowedWidth = scrollView.flickableItem.contentWidth - scrollView.viewport.width

                    if(row.width < scrollView.viewport.width){
                        return
                    }

                    var offset = scrollView.flickableItem.contentX + 50

                    if(offset <= allowedWidth){
                        scrollView.flickableItem.contentX += 50
                    }
                    else {
                        scrollView.flickableItem.contentX = allowedWidth
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollView {
            id: scrollView
            anchors.left: contentItem.left
            anchors.right: rightButton.left
            anchors.top: contentItem.top
            anchors.bottom: contentItem.bottom

            clip: true

            verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
            horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff

            property var imagesUrlModel: [
                "file:///C:/Users/mikha/OneDrive/Изображения/toyota.jpg",
                "file:///C:/Users/mikha/OneDrive/Изображения/toyota.jpg"
            ]

            Row {
                id: row
                spacing: 15

                Repeater {
                    id: repeater
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    model: scrollView.imagesUrlModel
                    delegate: Component {
                        id: imageDelegate

                        Image {
                            id: image

                            sourceSize.height: 300

                            source: modelData
                            fillMode: Image.Stretch
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example just change `listView.contentWidth` to `listView.contentWidth-listView.width` in `onClicked` event for `rightButton`. But that's not enough. You should check whether the `listView.contentX+50` is not overflowing `listView.contentWidth-listView.width` before you update the `listView.contentX`. In such case you need to update `listView.contentX` with difference between `listView.contentWidth` and `listView.width`.

Here it is:

```
listView.contentX = listView.contentX+50 <= listView.contentWidth-listView.width
                            ? listView.contentX + 50
                            : listView.contentWidth - listView.width
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems like it will not work. Because `listView.contentWidth` is not static it changes if  the image goes out of viewport and becames invisible. I used another approach with `repeater` and `scrollview`

Comment: I've tested it, and it's working. `listView.contentWidth` changes, but visible container part (listView.width) has constant width.

Comment: My mistake in comment above. I've checked that `contentWidth` also does not depend on images visibility, and is constant value of all images width and spacing beetween them.